# Search Variable for String then Run Conditional Statement in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am pretty new with PowerShell. I was recently tasked with making a error message popup that would help a local user determine whether or not a MS SQL on-demand DB merge worked or not. I wrote a script that woudld do the following:

Run the batch file that conducted the merge

Read the results of a text log file into a variable

Check the variable for any instances of the word "ERROR" and pop a success or fail dialog box depending on whether or not it found the word error in the log file.

Quick and simple I thought but I appear to be struggling with the conditional statement. Here is the script:

```
cmd /c c:\users\PERSON\desktop\merge.bat

$c = get-content c:\replmerg.log

if ($c -contains ("ERROR"))
{
    $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
    $b = $a.popup(“ERROR - Database Merge“,0,”Please Contact Support”,1)
}

else
{
    $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
    $b = $a.popup(“SUCCESS - Database Merge“,0,”Good Job!”,1)
}
```

Right now what happens is that the script runs and just skips to the Success message. I can confirm that simply running the 'get-content' command in powershell will on its own produce a variable that I can then call and show the content of the log file. My script however does not appear as though it is actually checking the $c variable for the word and then popping the error message as intended. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christian's answer is correct. You could also use the **-match** operator. For example:

```
if ((Get-Content c:\replmerg.log) -match "ERROR")
{
    'do error stuff'
}
else
{
    'do success stuff'
}
```

You can use **-cmatch** if you want a case sensitive comparison.

Comment: For some reason, Greg your if statement worked when Christian's produced the same result. Either way, thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome. :) Actually, the reason Christian's **if** fails is because **$c** actually is type **matchinfo** and there is no **length** property. When problems like this it always pays to know what type you're dealing with. Play with the different versions you've tried each time checking **$c.gettype()**.

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to use Get-Content at all. Select-String can take a -path parameter. I created two very simple text files, one which has the word ERROR and one which does not

```
PS C:\> cat .\noerror.txt
not in here
PS C:\> cat .\haserror.txt
ERROR in here
this has ERROR in here
PS C:\> if ( Select-String  -Path .\noerror.txt -Pattern ERROR) {"Has Error"}
PS C:\> if ( Select-String  -Path .\haserror.txt -Pattern ERROR) {"Has Error"}
Has Error
PS C:\>
```

The one thing that might trip you up is that the -pattern actually takes a regular expression, so be careful of what you use for your pattern. THis will find ERROR anywhere in the log file, even if there are multiple instances, like in my "haserror.txt" file.

Answer (score 1):

The -contains operator is used for looking for an exact match in a list (or array).  As the other answers indicate, you should use -match, -like, or -eq to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -quiet switch of select-string if you just wnat to test for the presence of a string in a file.

```
select-string -path c:\replmerg.log -pattern "ERROR" -casesensetive -quiet
```

Will return $true if the string is found in the file, and $false if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

contain operator test only an identical value (not part of a value).

You can try this

```
$c = get-content c:\replmerg.log | select-string "ERROR" -casesensitive

if ($c.length -gt 0)
```

Comment: Tried putting it in and it still just skips over the first IF statement and pops thesuccess message. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: strange... simulating here do a grat job! Maybe ERROR is low case writed?

Comment: actually there is no **length** property for the comparison to work because $c is type **matchinfo** if there are any matches otherwise $c is $null. Using **if ($c) { } else { }** should work just fine because you're an implicit **if ($c -eq $null)**.

Comment: @Greg: you're rigth! In my test, before posting the answer, I used a file with many matches! I was sure (w/o testing, big error) that always the return type was an array object. Thank you!